# How to keep dot files in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have installed some software in a docker image. When I run the software, it creates some setting files (dot files) under the root home folder. The problem is docker container wipes those files when I quit the container.

Is there a way to keep those dot files after I quite containers? I know I can manually save the container into a image. But that is not an elegant solution. That means every time I used the container, I need to save it to a image.

Any better solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a volume.

```
docker volume create configuration
```

And then you just run each container with it.

```
docker run -d -v configuration:container_configuration_dir your_image_name
```

Left side of `:` is name of volume created with first command and right side is dir inside container where your dot files are created.

Keep in mind how mounts work and for more details check [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) on volumes.